# Unique Id for MPMediaItem rather then persistentID

Tags: ios, swift, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaitem

By using the `persistentID` for uniquely identify the song but we have the provision in music app to add the same song multiple times to the playlist this tends to have same song many times in the playlist along with same persistentID so I can't able to the find out the which song is currently selecting because all the songs has the same `persistentID`. Is there any alternative to identify the MPMediaItem rather then `persistentID`.

NOTE: I can't decide through selected cell on the `UITableView` too because it has some other dependencies.

Comment: Subclass AVPlayer and add your personal ID field. I do this with a 'position in playlist' field which allows me to remember a track's order.

Answer (score 3):

How about using the `playbackStoreID` from MPMediaItem?

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaitem/2813404-playbackstoreid